# How can I clean up the Open With.. Menu

Tags: gnome

I've been using my desktop since the release of 10.10, and as per usual its very cluttered. I spent a few hours today tidying the system, and I've found a really annoying area that I'm unaware of how to fix. The Open With... dialog contains several duplicates and even bunk entires. How can I remove these?

[image: Screenshot-Open With.png]

**EDIT:** I've also stumbled across a great tutorial on this subject http://greeennotebook.com/2010/11/clean-up-the-open-with-menu-in-ubuntu-10-10/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

right click on the file . select the properties and click on the 'Open With' tab. Select the application you want to remove and click  the button 'Remove' to remove that item from the 'Open With' menu.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this cleaning the wrong menu? This is for the right click menu, but in OPs example it shows the "Open with..." dialog.

Answer (score 11):

You can remove the duplicate entries in
**~/.local/share/applications**

Comment: THIS really can help to clean that menu, thanks