# How to edit the "Open With..." menu?

Tags: configuration

[image]

As shown in the screenshot above, there are many multiple duplicated entries for same application when using the `open with` menu.

`open with` appears when right click on a file or whatever and choose `open with`

My question: How to reset this menu or delete the duplicated entries?!

**PS** This is not duplicate. This answer here [How can I clean up the Open With.. Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15820/how-can-i-clean-up-the-open-with-menu)  is not valid anymore.

**Another PS**: Those are wine apps, but the status is same even for native apps, moreover those wine apps I've already uninstall most of them

**I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Nautilus 3.4.2**

Comment: Since those are Wine apps, I think you need to uninstall then reinstall them.

Comment: There is other than wine apps, Moreover most of them i uninstalled already

Comment: Was this the page you found? http://askubuntu.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-remove-change-the-open-with-list

Comment: @Zacharee1 this option is not found anymore in nautilus

Comment: It's not part of nautilus. You need to right click the file you're trying to open.

Comment: It's part of nautilus friend. The right click and all subsequences in it is a nautilus extension

Comment: @Zacharee1 Moreover forget association deals with apps that is associated to specific type of files but i want to remove entries from open with which is not associated...

Comment: Nuke everything related to wine in `.local/share/applications`,  including entries in `mimeapps.list`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mimeopen .doc` at the terminal to see for example which applications are associated with the `.doc` file extension and then go to `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` directory and remove the extensions associated with uninstalled applications.

You can then apply a similar approach to other file extensions.

Comment: +1 for your idea but this would be tough job to do. I'm looking for something simpler. but if i don't find i'll consider your answer

Comment: I think this is the only solution unless you find a GUI application that does this for you…

Comment: If you want to reset everything and use the system defaults, you could just remove the whole ~/.local/share/applications directory (note: this will also affect custom Unity launcher icons), since there's a system-wide /usr/share/applications with a sane configuration.